# How to perform lead and lag in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo, studio3t

I am  using STudio 3T and I have query like this:

```
select [Dashbo],lead([Dashbo]) over(order by [Entered Date])
from ATest_prevback;
```

This is giving me and error. How to perform this in MongoDB? Can someone give me an example?

Thanks,
Adi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from MongoDB v5.0+, it can be done by using [$shift](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/shift/#examples) in [$setWindowFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-setWindowFields).

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": null,
      "sortBy": {
        "entered_date": 1
      },
      "output": {
        lag: {
          $shift: {
            output: "$Dashbo",
            by: -1,
            default: "Not available"
          }
        },
        lead: {
          $shift: {
            output: "$Dashbo",
            by: 1,
            default: "Not available"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mCOGKlRI8Rb) for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not possible.

**Workaround:** Create a [Materialized view](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/materialized-views/) with calculated data.

Run in the MongoDB Shell:

---

```
var prev = null;
db.ATest_prevback.find({}).sort({field:1}).forEach(function(curr){
    db.materialized_view.insert({curr:curr.field, prev:(prev ? prev.field : 0)})
    prev = curr;
})
```

---

Run "fake" `lead` and `lag` queries:

```
db.materialized_view.aggregate([
    {$match:{$expr:{$eq:["$curr", "$prev"]}}}
])
```